# Is there an appropriate parting phrase to someone leaving on bad trip?

Tags: greetings

If someone you know is leaving for a vacation it's appropriate to say something like "have a good trip"

A colleague was going on a trip to visit his terminally ill mother. On his last day in the office we talked briefly and I said "well, have a good trip" at the end of our conversation. I quickly realized this was inappropriate because he isn't going there to have a good time.

What would be an appropriate parting phrase in this situation? I wanted to express concern and hope for his mother and at the same time wish him safe travels.

Comment: *Have a safe journey* would be an equally sensitive expression to say to a friend before a trip.

Answer (score 2):

"Take care of yourself" might be good, and "Again, I'm so sorry" would be appropriate in this instance.